# Parse database table from GET request

Tags: php, mysql, database, parsing, request

Good morning
I've been struggling to work arround this recently, as I'm fairly new to PHP & MySQL in general. 
I have a database with a table "videos" in which I store useful informations about videos and I have a document called search.php who will display specific videos based on GET Request.
A Request looks like this:

```
http://example.ex/search.php?tag=EXAMPLE1
```

The logic would be to store the tag value like this:

```
if(!empty($_GET["tag"])){
     // Get videos from tag only
     $curTag = strval($_GET["tag"]);
     displayByTag($curTag); //the function that parse the database
}
```

I have my connection ready:

```
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "mydatabase";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db);

$query = "SELECT * FROM videos";
$response = array();
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $response[] = $row;
}
```

Technically as of right now, my table is stored inside `$response[].`
What I need to do is to parse the database and looks for the "tags" column, split its string value ("EXAMPLE1,EXAMPLE2,EXAMPLE3" in table) and then see if the GET value matches one of them.

That's when I need your help. I understand the logic, the steps, but can't "translate" it into PHP. Here's what I would do (human-language):

```
function displayByTag($tag) {
     for each $video-item inside $array {
          $tagsArray = explodes(",", $video-item[tags-column]); //That's how I split the tags stored inside the table
          for i as integer = 0 to $tagsArray.length {
               if $tagsArray(i) == $tag {
                    //THATS A MATCH
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it ? And how can I translate that "human" language into PHP code ?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of testing and debugging I got my function working pretty easily. If anyone is interested:

```
function searchVideos($search) {
    $currentSearchQueries = explode(" ", strtoupper($search)); //Split the searched tags in a array and make them to uppercase for easier comparaison.

    //Establish a connection the MySql Database
    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "mydatabase";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db);

    //Select all the entries from my 'videos' table
    $query = "SELECT * FROM videos";
    $response = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $response[] = $row; //Place them into a array
    }

    //Parse the array for matching entries
    foreach ($response as &$video){ //Each entries goes through the process
        foreach ($currentSearchQueries as $t) {
            //We compare if one the tags searched matches for this particular entry
            if((strtoupper($video[tags]) == $t) {
                //THAT'S A MATCH
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It was very fun to code, looking forward for new experiences !